# After defining a new bone chain the Rig is not generated (no error displayed)

Tags: rigging, bones

Good morning everyone, I am new to the forum so if you have any advice/comments on how I wrote the post I will be more than happy to receive them.
I'll try to explain the situation: using Blender (v 2.9) I've built a 3D model of a character and now I'd like to try to move it to make simple animations (running, jumping etc.). To do this I have seen that it is necessary to define an "armor" and then generate a "rig" in order to make it easier and faster to pose the character.
I was able to understand how to set a basic armor (only the human body) and generate the rig of this, but my model is more complex, below I attach photos:

[image: Front View]
[image: Back View]
[![Lateral View][3]][3]
[image]
[image]

NOTE: I am not an expert of the Blender environment.

To understand how to use the "rig" function using already defined chains I followed the video tutorial shown at the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZFnrvsZ-ds&ab_channel=CGDive

The problem I have now is to define a chain of bones for the upper and lower arms that allows the generation of a working rig exactly like that of normal arms.

I try to explain better: if you look at the image below you will see the armor that I built following the tutorial at the link above and the rig generated. And this is correct.

[image: Rig from video-tutorial]

Now I generate a new chain of bones (by pressing shift+a) and extrude the bones I need. That done, I apply keep-offset to bind the newly generated bone chain to the rest of the armor:

[image: Adding new bone chain]

At this point, going to "Object Mode" and clicking on Generate Rig, only the basic rig is generated, but not the one for the chain I built and I don't understand why (image follows):

[image: New Rig]

I've tried to use the chain of bones related to the spine, or to modify the one of a leg, but without results.

**Conclusions**:

- Can you help me understand how I get a working rig for the other 4 arms as well (with the same movement properties of the normal arms) ?
- Also, if I want to move the reticle that I have made on the back of my character, in the sense that it also moves as a result of the movement of the 4 arms how could I do?

Thanks in advance of your help and support.

Comment: Rigify is modular and comes with predefined metarigs (that's what you called "armor"). These metarigs are templates for humans (basic & detailed), birds, cats, dogs, etc. They are used to align the bones to the mesh. Have you done this you can generate the final rig. If you want to have 4 more arms you need to extend the human meta rig with Rig Types bones (building blocks). Adding a simple bone chain doesn't work. Todor (CGDive) has a complete series about customized Rigify rigs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JSFcSxsaTs&list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx

Answer (score 0):

You followed the tutorial for the two "normal" arms, right? Why don't you repeat the process for the additional arms? Just add two more arms "samples" align them to the mesh and symmetrize them.